# Is it better to have my JMenus in their own class or all in the same class?

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextpane, jmenu

Right now I am creating a simple text editor. I want to know is better/cleaner to have all of my JMenus in their own class or in the same class as each other? Each JMenu would have its own number of JMenuItems, along with the listeners and functionality that goes with it; each of those objects would have a couple hundred lines of code. If I were to put them all in their own classes, would it be "okay" to have the JTextPane to simply add those JMenu object to it? Would that class, the JTextPane class, seem too "empty", since all it would essentially do is:

```
Menu1 menuObj1 = new Menu1 ();
menuObj.buildItemsAndStuff();
Menu2 menuObj2 = new Menu2();
menuObj3.buildItemsAndStuff();
menuObj2.buildItemsAndStuff();

textPaneObj.add(menuObj1);
textPaneObj.add(menuObj2);
...and so on
```

Comment: Since it is a subjective answer you're looking for, here is mine. I always use them in the same class and do not think it is bad coding.

Answer (score 1):

The objective of object oriented code is to provide a class that will instantiate few objects. Thus, the best in my opinion would be to have a general class MyMenu, and then :

```
MyMenu menu1 = new MyMenu(parameters);
MyMenu menu2 = new MyMenu(parameters);
```

Nevertheless, sometimes, it may be better to have a specific class for each menu. If it really is your case and if your menu will be used in only one class of your code, I advice you to create your menu as an inner class.

Anyway, this is both subjective and case by case dependant.